# Dynamic content in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am making  a quote website and i want to link each Author to a page where I can set his/her  quotes so should I make a single html page for each one of them or there is an easy way to do that, ty

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Have a database and use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an "easy" way to do that.
It depends of what do you use to create this website.

Did you use any kind of CMS like WordPress? Or you are still using only HTML, CSS and Javascript?

In the second case, you will have do some back-end app to bring this dynamically.

Comment: Where should I start  if  I want to make a back end-app, and is that the easy way ?

Comment: When I mean "easy", I mean easier than making it all manually.
Making a back-end app, you can start studying NodeJS for an API and database, then bring the data with Javascript in the front-end.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.